# Creating New Images in Preview

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, preview, image-editing

It seems to me that the macOS Preview app's purpose is to edit existing images. I'm wondering if it's possible to create new images from scratch. For example, I would like to create an illustration with some paintbrushes. Instinctively I'm looking for File -> New Image, but it doesn't seem to exist in Preview. Please advise.

Comment: I would have a plain white jpg of a reasonable size handy that you can open and then save as... Also Preview is not designed as a paint app. It started life as a quick way to "preview" (ahem....) graphics files and has evolved into a simple touch-up, graphic manipulation app. So no you can't create a new graphic in Preview, as for it's suitability as a painting tool, well you get what you pay for.

Comment: Since this isn't possible in Preview, do you want recommendations of (free) software that can do this?

Comment: @abc that would be great. I'm looking for something free and simple.  GIMP was a pain to use. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it isn't possible to create new images with Preview, as it is just meant for doing basic edits on images.(see @SteveChambers' comment)

If you really want to use Preview and not another app, just find a white image of the size you want and open it in Preview to edit and draw on it.

Otherwise, you can use 3rd party software:

- [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/), a free and open-source image editor with many capabilities, including creating and drawing images(fun fact: the very first Google logo was created in this program)
- [Keynote](https://www.apple.com/keynote/), made by Apple as a presentation app, but can also be used for simple drawings
- [Pixelmator](https://www.pixelmator.com/) (paid), a user-friendly image editor with many drawing/painting capabilities
- [Acorn](https://flyingmeat.com/acorn/) (paid), a user-friendly image editor with many drawing/painting capabilities

Comment: Please include Photoshop here. It is probably the most relevant. And it is possible, but pointless. I will add a pointless answer.

Comment: @JBis I only wanted to include lower priced software since OP is only doing basic drawing, and even then GIMP and Affinity Photo together as good as, if not better, than Photoshop.